# Does $P(x_1, y_1,x_2, y_2) = P(x_1, y_1)P(x_2,y_2)$ imply $P(y_2 \mid x_1, y_1, x_2) = P(y_2 \mid x _2)$?

Tags: probability

Say $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are independent. So that $p(x_1, y_1, x_2, y_2) = p(x_1, y_1)p(x_2, y_2)$. Does this imply that $p(y_2 \mid x_2) = p(y_2 \mid x_1, y_1, x_2)$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it does.

To do it all a little tedious, first get by definition

$$p(y_2\lvert x_1,y_1,x_2) := \frac{p(y_2 ,x_1,y_1,x_2)}{p(x_1,y_1,x_2)}$$

Then by integration and using independence
$$ = \frac{p(y_2 ,x_1,y_1,x_2)}{\int p(y_2,x_1,y_1,x_2) dy_2} = \frac{p(y_1 ,x_1)p(y_2,x_2)}{\int p(y_2,x_2)p(y_1,x_1) dy_2}  = \frac{p(y_1 ,x_1)p(y_2,x_2)}{p(x_2)p(y_1,x_1) }  = \frac{p(y_2,x_2)}{p(x_2) }$$

and finally by definition

$$= p(y_2\lvert x_2)$$